# iphone app approved but bug found before release

Tags: iphone, version, release

I just got my app approved....but realised there is a bug that will need a small fix. I do not want to release this app with the bug.

I am unsure how to get this fixed. If I submit another binary it will go through the review process again. I will also need to put a new version (1.1).

If I still have to submit a new version, can I directly release the new version (1.1) and completely ignore version 1.0?

Thanks in advance for advise..

pm

Answer (score 2):

You would have to reject your binary for 1.0 and resubmit either a 1.0 or greater binary.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the release date of an approved app into the future and then submit an update.  If the update is approved, pull the release date back.  The current version need never be visible in the App store.

If you put in your comments field that this is a critical bug fix, then there is a possibility (but no guarantee) that the review period may be a few days shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change version. You can keep version 1.0 and change build  1.1. Then Submit app for review process.

Answer (score -1):

If your application has been approved, then it's available in the appStore.
The only solution for you to fix this bug is to send a new version of your application with unfortunately the Apple review process. (We just got the same issue)

From here, 1.0 will be ignored for new downloaders and those who have installed it would have to update the app.

Comment: You can set the release date into the future to remove an app from the App store (within hours).

Comment: This isn't true. App that are approved are not necessarily released to the app store.

Comment: Well, 5 years later, things have changed.